# Fastcgi request record is too big

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, configuration, http, fastcgi

I am running an Nginx server, which requires me to accept URI String containing up to 4mb of data.

I have configured nginx to accept the params by setting:

*/etc/nginx/nginx.conf*

```
large_client_header_buffers 18 2048k;
client_header_buffer_size 10m;
```

The server now accepts the request, however it throws an **Internal Error 500**.
Looking in the *site-error.log*, this is what I get:

```
1 fastcgi request record is too big: 2425046
```

And looking at the request, it's been cut down to about 4k of data. 
Is it possible to accept requests this large, and how?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to send the data via GET request? Why just don't use POST as it was created for large data input?

---

**EDIT 1:**

It is very complicated to do this with nginx. If you still want to send it via get, install Apache instead of nginx and just edit [LimitRequestLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891574/how-do-i-resolve-a-http-414-request-uri-too-long-error) param as suggested

Comment: That is how the API was initially designed. The data has grown considerably since.

Comment: @Kao Time for a new version of the API. Trying to send 4MB of data in a GET request is unwise for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @Kao It is very complicated to do this with nginx. If you still want to send it via get, install Apache instead of nginx and just edit [limitrequestline](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline) param

Comment: @Michael Hampton . We are working on this, but as we have a lot of clients running this monster, we need it for a while still, unfortunately.